# Coq ssreflect - rewrite inside \big

Tags: coq, coq-mathcomp, coq-ssreflect

I'm trying to prove the following lemma :

```ml
Definition SequenceSum {K : fieldType} (s : nat -> K) (n : nat) := \sum_(0 <= i < n.+1) s i.

Lemma one_minus_q_product_development {K : fieldType} (q : K) (n : nat) : (1-q) * SequenceSum (fun (i:nat) => q^+i) n = 1 - q^+(n+1).
```

I have currently done this :

```ml
Proof.
  rewrite /SequenceSum mulrBl.
  rewrite {1}big_nat_recl//.
  rewrite sum_distrr.
  rewrite big_nat_recr//.
```

So the current goal is :

```ml
  K : fieldType
  q : K
  n : nat
  ============================
  1 * (q ^+ 0 + \sum_(0 <= i < n) q ^+ i.+1) - GRing.add_monoid K (\big[GRing.add_monoid K/0]_(0 <= i < n) (q * q ^+ i)) (q * q ^+ n) = 1 - q ^+ (n + 1)
```

I'm seeking to use the `exprS : forall (R : ringType) (x : R) (n : nat), x ^+ n.+1 = x * x ^+ n` in order to turn the `q * q +^ i` into `q ^+ i.+1`, but upon using `rewrite -exprS`, it only rewrites the `q * q ^+ n` (note that it is outside of any `\sum`) into `q ^+ n.+1`.

`rewrite -2!exprS` yields the following error :

```ml
Error: At iteration 2: The RHS of exprS
    (_ * _ ^+ _)
does not match any subterm of the goal
```

Despite `q * q +^ i` being in the goal.

Any ideas on how to use this lemma in order to rewrite a term inside a `\sum` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this file](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/master/mathcomp/ssreflect/bigop.v) you'll see examples of using `under eq_bigr ... do ...` which is how you do such inside rewrites.